# How can I make the android navigation bar transparent when React Native Modal is shown?

Tags: android, react-native, android-alertdialog, android-navigation-bar, react-native-modal

I use React Native CLI. With Alert, the full screen of the app is covered and the navigation bar becomes transparent. However this does not happen with a Modal, which does not cover the navigation bar. (and it looks a bit bad). I don't understand why that happens and I'd be grateful if someone could help me out.

[Example when using Modal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCjqm.jpg)

[Example when using Alert.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzP1a.jpg)

Comment: This [library](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/navigation-bar/) might be of help. Using this you can control the transparency of nav bar while displaying modal.

Comment: @sushrut619 Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention in the post that I use React Native CLI, not Expo. Do you know any equivalent library that could work for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting transparent prop to 'true' - https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#transparent

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried setting transparent to true, but it still does not cover the navigation bar.